# Does Expo EAS Update require fetchUpdateAsync?

Tags: react-native, expo

So I'm trying to implement Expo Updates for my managed, standalone build Expo App running SDK 46 following the instructions here: https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/getting-started/

I'm not having much luck though.

The docs for setup state nothing more than:

```
npx expo install expo-updates
eas update:configure
eas build:configure
```

which just alter `eas.json` and `app.json`. Is that really all I should need? The docs for the package here: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/updates/ talk about API methods like `Updates.fetchUpdateAsync()` but there's no example code. Do I need to implement that in my app somewhere?

Any advice much appreciated!